# React: disable a filtered item

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an activity, where a user needs to match two words on click. Like on the picture below.
[image]

If words match they should get disabled. 
My state is following

```
this.state = {
      data: [],
      mixedWords: [],
      myanswers: [],
      allPairs: [],
      checked: false,
      isCorrect: false,
      isIncorrect: false
    };
```

For example `myanswers` array maybe like this.
["more than", "более"]

`mixedWords` array is the following

```
[{translation: "more than", disabled: false},
 {translation: "capital", disabled: false},
 {word: "более", disabled: false},
 {translation: "famous", disabled: false},
 {word: "проживает", disabled: false},
 {translation: "is living", disabled: false},
 {word: "известный", disabled: false},
 {word: "столице", disabled: false}
 ]
```

This function is responsible for modifying disabled property. But the problem is that it outputs only filtered items. How can I output `mixedWords` array with modifyed `disabled` property for specific items

```
const myFunction = (value) => {
    const mixedWords = [...this.state.mixedWords]
    const result = mixedWords.filter(word => word.translation === value || word.word === value );
    const newResult = Object.assign({}, result[0], { disabled:true })
    this.setState({
      mixedWords:[newResult]
      })
     }
    this.state.myanswers.forEach(myFunction)
```

Full code

```
/* eslint-disable no-extend-native */
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import click from "../data/media/click.wav";
//import correct from "../data/media/correct.wav";
//import denied from "../data/media/denied.mp3";
let _ = require("lodash");

class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      mixedWords: [],
      myanswers: [],
      allPairs: [],
      checked: false,
      isCorrect: false,
      isIncorrect: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let mixedWords = [];
    let allPairs = [];
    this.props.data.quiz && this.props.data.quiz.map((item) => {
      mixedWords.push({word:item.word, disabled:false},{ translation:item.translation,disabled:false});
      allPairs.push(item.pair);
      return (mixedWords, allPairs);
    });

    this.setState({
      data: this.props.data.quiz,
      mixedWords: _.shuffle(mixedWords),
      allPairs
    });
    //console.log(this.props.data);
  }

  selectWords = (e) => {
    let items = e.target.value;
    let myanswers = this.state.myanswers.concat(items);
    this.setState({ myanswers }, () => {
      if (this.state.myanswers.length === 2) {
        if (this.checkAnswers(this.state.myanswers, this.state.allPairs)) {
          console.log("correct");

          const myFunction = (value) => {
            const mixedWords = [...this.state.mixedWords]
            const result = mixedWords.filter(word => word.translation === value || word.word === value );
            const newResult = Object.assign({}, result[0], { disabled:true })
            this.setState({
              mixedWords:[newResult]
            })
          }

          this.state.myanswers.forEach(myFunction)
          this.setState({
            myanswers:[]
          })
        } else {
          console.log("incorrect");
          this.setState({
            myanswers:[]
          })
        }
      } else {
        console.log('choose a pair');
      }
    });

  };

  checkAnswers = (answersArr, allPairs) => {
    let bools = []
    allPairs.forEach((arr) => {
      this.arraysEqual(answersArr, arr);
      //console.log(this.arraysEqual(answersArr, arr));
      //console.log(arr, this.state.myanswers);
      bools.push(this.arraysEqual(answersArr, arr))
    });

    if (bools.includes(true)) {
      return true
    }
  };

  arraysEqual = (a, b) => {
    return a.sort().toString() === b.sort().toString() 
  };



  render() {
    console.log(this.state.mixedWords);
    console.log(this.state.myanswers);
    //console.log(this.state.allPairs);
    //console.log(this.state.myanswers.join(" ") === this.state.answers.join(" "));
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tags are-medium">
          { this.state.mixedWords.map((item) => (
            <button disabled={item.disabled} value={ item.word || item.translation } onClick={ (e) => { this.selectWords(e); } } className="tag is-warning">{ item.word || item.translation }</button>
          )) }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Quiz;
```

Comment: Use array::map, it returns an array that is the same length as the one it mapped from, and when you get to the element with the match, create the new object with disabled property you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work for me.

Comment: Oh boy, I spent a bit of time just trying to get your code to run, you've a lot of weird code patterns going on and `myFunction` not working might not even be the biggest issue. You've got to sort out your array function use, it's all over the place. Best I can tell is you are using the array::filter as a find function to update a single element that was in `mixedWords`, but then when you save that back into state you don't keep the rest of the `mixedWords` array. Perhaps that is what you are seeing? I still think array::map is what you want, with the suggestion from my first comment.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I was able to implement it using map function, thanks

Comment: Great. I was going to ask if you could provide a working codesandbox but it is working now for you that is great.

Comment: There is one issue though, disabled is modified only for one item only.

Comment: I assume when you have a "match" you want to disable both words of the match?

Comment: yes, exactly, it disbles only one

Answer (score 0):

```
selectWords = (e) => {
    let items = e.target.value;
    let myanswers = this.state.myanswers.concat(items);
    this.setState({ myanswers }, () => {
      if (this.state.myanswers.length === 2) {
        if (this.checkAnswers(this.state.myanswers, this.state.allPairs)) {
          console.log("correct");
          const myFunction = (value) => {
            this.setState({
              mixedWords:this.state.mixedWords.map(word => word.translation === value || word.word === value ? Object.assign({}, word, { disabled:true }) : word)
            })
          }
          this.state.myanswers.forEach(myFunction)
          this.setState({
            myanswers:[]
          })
        } else {
          console.log("incorrect");
          this.setState({
            myanswers:[]
          })
        }
      } else {
        console.log('choose a pair');
      }
    });

  };
```

Comment: I believe it is `this.state.myanswers.forEach(myFunction)`, the effect of `myFunction` is to setState, and when you have two answers, both state updates are queued in the same render cycle and the second update wipes out the first. You should look at both words at the same time in `myFunction` where you do the mapping. Something like `this.state.mixedWords.map(word => myanswers.includes(word.translation) || myanswers.includes(word.word) ? ...`